# How to stub Spring repository to throw an exception in an integration test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-test

I have a service which has a repository as a constructor's parameter.

```
@Autowired
NodeServiceListInstallService( final BykiListRepository aBykiListRepository )
```

The `BykiListRepository` is default Spring repository without implementation

```
interface BykiListRepository extends JpaRepository<BykiList, Long> {
    //some magic methods
}
```

My configuration class marked with `@EnableJpaRepositories`, so, I haven't direct bean's declaration. Service declaration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties( ApplicationProperties )
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource( 'classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml' )
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    NodeServiceListInstallService nodeServiceListInstallService( final BykiListRepository bykiListRepository ) {
        new NodeServiceListInstallService( bykiListRepository )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test within of the call of the repository's method `save` will thrown an exception `PersistenceException`.
I've tried to stub/spy a a repository and declare it as a bean in `@TestConfiguration` with `@Primary`, or even implement the interface.
But I haven't got the result.

```
@TestConfiguration
class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    BykiListRepository bykiListRepository() {
        //return Spock's Spy/Stub or new BykiRepositoryBadImpl()
    }
```

Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration( classes = TestConfig )
class GlobalErrorHandlerIntegrationTest extends BaseFlowIntegrationTest {
    //test()
}
```

I write on `Groovy-2.4.12` and write tests with `Spock-1.1`. `Spring Boot 1.5.4`.
Reserved variant is to use aspect, but there's not exactly what I wish.
Will be very grateful for help.

Update: Usage of `DetachedMockFactory`:

Configuration:

@TestConfiguration

```
class DummyConfiguration {
    private final detachedFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()
    @Bean
    @Primary
    BykiListRepository bykiListRepository() {
        detachedFactory.Mock( BykiListRepository )
    }
}
```

Test's skeleton:

```
@SpringBootTest( classes = DummyConfiguration )
@Import( [DummyConfiguration] )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = DummyConfiguration )
class GlobalErrorHandlerIntegrationTest extends BaseFlowIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    BykiListRepository bykiListRepositoryMock
    def 'exercise error handling'() {
        given: 'the failing repository'
        bykiListRepositoryMock.save( _ ) >> {
            throw new CannotCreateTransactionException()
        }
        when: 'the message is send to rabbit'
        rabbitOperations.send( configuration.rabbitExchangeName, '', msg )
    }
}
```

where:

```
@SpringBootTest( webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = Application )
class BaseFlowIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {...}
```

And

```
@Category( InboundIntegrationTest )
abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest extends Specification {...}
```

Comment: Did you check documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: @AnarSultanov Yes, and I don't understand how it could help in my case. Could you give some explanation or examples??

Comment: please provide the test example, especially how you creating and initializing SpringContext

Comment: You can use Mockito or any mocking framework

Comment: @Yogi I use Spock. It allows mocking. The problem is how to replace the injecting repository bean.

Comment: firstly you don t need to define service as bean just add service or component it will be invoked at runtime

Comment: @Mr.Ustiik - you can use DetachedMockFactory for this...follow this link- https://objectpartners.com/2017/04/18/spring-integration-testing-with-spock-mocks/

Comment: @Yogi it don't work. Look at update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I had wrong bean name. I've changed it to the `bykiListRepositoryMock` (instead of `bykiListRepository`) and it've solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `test configuration` like below and using Spock record when calling some function then ex will be thrown. Of course, use `@Inject or @Autowire` in test class... and do `@Import([IntegrationTestMockingConfig])`

```
@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationTestMockingConfig {

     private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

     @Bean
     ExternalRepository externalRepository() {
         factory.Mock(ExternalRepository)
     }
}
```

Comment: No error. Just the real bean injected. The breakpoint within the test bean creating (`factory.Mock(ExternalRepository)` - this line) don't executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an exception using your mocked repository -

`when(repository.yourMethodName(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenThrow(new PersistenceException("Persistence exception occurred"));`

If you want to throw any specific persistence exception then you can also throw.
https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/exceptions